# How to build a 64-bit .NET DLL, with 64-bit COM interop?

Tags: .net, interop, activex, 64-bit

I need to build a managed DLL, targeted for x64, and expose it via x64 COM. I need a walk through, good article, etc...

Interop is fairly straightforward, but when you talk about x64 on both sides, I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this discussion](http://bytes.com/forum/thread584555.html).
And [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/bbb164c7-9d76-4804-b506-85172e586e99/).