# Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location

Tags: com

I have created a COM dll in .Net and build it under Any CPU. I am using that COM dll in Vcpp code but getting Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location error when creating the pointer reference to COM class. The VCPP code works perfectly fine if the Build configuration is Win32 but if i change the configuration to X64 mode then teh application crashes.

Please Help

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using a so-called *in process* DLL, you have to use the 64 bits version of that DLL in your program.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95628/how-to-build-a-64-bit-net-dll-with-64-bit-com-interop) discusses it. It seems that you have to use the 64 bit regasm tool to register your .NET DLL.

Comment: Either this or host it in a surrogate process.

Comment: Thanks for the post, the problem is solved using 64 bit regasm. I have another query and tried doing a lot of google but no success. I am using the COM dll in VCPP dll (Active Directory dll) and the import path i gave was relative(only Comdll name), i added the absolute path in Tools-> Additional Include Directory. i stored my vcpp dll in system32 folder, which is invoking the COM dll method stored in "C:\test" folder. how can i make the tlb path dynamic? as my VCPP dll is stored in system32 folder.

Comment: @Haseena: please open another question for this.